# Make a dropdown for a WooCommerce taxonomy like product tags

Tags: php, jquery, woocommerce, shortcode, custom-taxonomy

I have found this post ([Make tag show as dropdown in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39568407/make-tag-show-as-dropdown-in-woocommerce)) that gets part of this function in place, but the output is incorrect. When using this snippet, the results output only post tags instead of product tags.

```
<label><?php _e('Tags'); ?></label>
<form action="<?php bloginfo('url'); ?>/" method="get">
    <div>
        <?php
        $args = array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_tag', // Taxonomy to return. Valid values are 'category', 'post_tag' or any registered taxonomy.
            'show_option_none' => 'Select tag',
            'show_count' => 1,
            'orderby' => 'name',
            'value_field' => 'slug',
            'echo' => 0
        );
        $select = wp_dropdown_categories( $args );
        $select = preg_replace("#<select([^>]*)>#", "<select$1 onchange='return this.form.submit()'>", $select);
        echo $select;
        ?>
        <noscript><div><input type="submit" value="View" /></div></noscript>
    </div>
</form>
```

The current snippet results in this output: https://www.website.com/?cat=books
It should result in: https://www.website.com/product-tag/books/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a custom dropdown for any WooCommerce product taxonomy as a shortcode that can be used everywhere, this way:

```
add_shortcode( 'product_tax_dropdown', 'wc_product_taxonomy_dropdown' );
function wc_product_taxonomy_dropdown( $atts ) {
    // Attributes
    $atts = shortcode_atts( array(
        'hide_empty'   => '1', // or '0'
        'show_count'   => '1', // or '0'
        'orderby'      => 'name', // or 'order'
        'taxonomy'     => 'product_tag',
    ), $atts, 'product_tax_dropdown' );

    global $wp_query;

    $taxonomy      = $atts['taxonomy'];
    $taxonomy_name = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy )->labels->singular_name;

    ob_start();

    wp_dropdown_categories( array(
        'hide_empty' => $atts['hide_empty'],
        'show_count' => $atts['show_count'],
        'orderby'    => $atts['orderby'],
        'selected'           => isset( $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars[$taxonomy] : '',
        'show_option_none'   => sprintf( __( 'Select a %s', 'woocommerce' ), $taxonomy_name ),
        'option_none_value'  => '',
        'value_field'        => 'slug',
        'taxonomy'   => $taxonomy,
        'name'       => $taxonomy,
        'class'      => 'dropdown_'.$taxonomy,
    ) );

    ?>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        jQuery(function($){
            var select = '.dropdown_product_tag',
                taxonomy = '<?php echo $taxonomy; ?>';

            function onProductTaxChange() {
                if ( $(select).val() !=='' ) {
                    location.href = '<?php echo esc_url( home_url() ); ?>/?'+taxonomy+'='+$(select).val();
                }
            }
            $(select).change( onProductTaxChange );
        });
    </script>
    <?php

    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and work.

---

**USAGE**

1) as a normal shortcode (in the Wordpress text editor or widgets):

```
[product_tax_dropdown];
```

2) In PHP templates, pages and functions shortcode:

```
echo do_shortcode('[product_tax_dropdown]');
```

Comment: Hi there, thank you so much for your response! The dropdown is created, but there is no page change on any of the selected tags. I'm getting syntax error (Unexptected token),  http://esprima.org/demo/validate.html

Comment: @joy I have tested it again and it just work perfectly for me without any issue.

Comment: shucks...I'm not sure what the issue is then. Did you notice that the syntax validator cites errors in the code? I appreciate that you took the time to respond and test - it's just not working for me. :-(

Comment: Wait! It works. I was using the text widget, and it didn't work there. But when I moved the shortcode into a custom html widget...it now works. Which is strange because shortcodes can be used using the text widget too. THANK YOU!!