# How to add "order by product tag alphabetically" in custom dropdown list in WooCommerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, tags, product, alphabetical

Inspired by [Make tag show as dropdown in woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50041764/14383628)

This allowed me to add a dropdown to WooCommerce to show all my record labels artists in it. I modified it a little bit.

I have already found to have the "`VIEW ALL`" option show up as the top results by move the show all option to before the foreach loop that creates the options for the different labels.

---

**My question:** Is it possible to add a "`VIEW ALL A-Z`" to order all results alphabetically to the list? I haven't found a code that would actually work on my site to order by tags so that's why I'm trying to achieve this via this code.

This is my code already slightly modified:

```php
function displayArtistDropdown() {

  $html = '';
    $html .= '<form class="artist-select" method="post">';
    $html .= '<select id="artist-selector" name="artist" class="artist">';

    $tag = wp_tag_cloud( array(
        'format' => 'array',
        'taxonomy' => 'product_tag' 
    ) );
    $page_path = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
    $page_url = site_url() . $page_path;
    $url_parts = parse_url($page_url);
    $constructed_url = $url_parts['scheme'] . '://' . $url_parts['host'] . (isset($url_parts['path'])?$url_parts['path']:'');

    $html .= '<option value="#">SELECT ARTIST</option>';
    $html .= '<option value="' . $constructed_url . '">View All Artists</option>';

    foreach($tag as $tagkey => $tagvalue)
    {
        $cleanedup = strip_tags($tagvalue);
        $tag_info = get_term_by('name', $cleanedup, 'product_tag', 'ARRAY_A');
        $tag_slug = $tag_info['slug'];
        if(isset($_GET['product_tag'])) { /// I am not sure if it is necessery
            $value_url = $constructed_url . '?product_tag=' . $tag_slug;
        } else {
            $value_url = $page_url . '?product_tag=' . $tag_slug;
        }
        /// (this prevent duplicate in URL in my case) $value_url = site_url() . '?product_tag=' . $tag_slug;
        $html .= '<option value="' . $value_url . '">' . $cleanedup . '</option>';
    }

    $html .= '</select>';
    $html .= '</form>';

    echo $html;
}

add_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'displayArtistDropdown', 40);

add_action('wp_head', 'addDisplayArtistScript');
function addDisplayArtistScript() {
    $script = '';
    $script .= '<script type="text/javascript">';
    $script .= 'jQuery(document).ready(function() {';
    $script .= '    jQuery("#artist-selector").change(function() {';
    $script .= '        location = jQuery("#artist-selector option:selected").val();';
    $script .= '    });';
    $script .= '});';
    $script .= '</script>';

    echo $script;
}
```

Comment: ok! Got the solution for number 1 problem: "move the show all option to before the foreach loop that creates the options for the different labels."